# Getting variables from Tag Manager dataLayer

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to get variables that are pushed into the dataLayer to be used as part of Analytics Event Tracking. The values are being added with this :

```
 dataLayer.push({
            'location' : 'header',
            'linkname' : gaTrackInfo
        });
```

Using console I can see that these variables are being created :

[image: Example of console showing values pushed into dataLayer]

In the Tag Manger UI I set up macros to watch for these variables :

[image: Macros in Tag Manager UI]

And I am trying to get them into the Event Tracking with something like :

[image: Calling variables into event tracking]

However when I watch in Real Time analytics these vars are always blank :

So from the examples in the screens I would hope to see the category testinglocheader but it just returns testingloc.  Any advice on what else I should be looking for to test this.  I know it is tracking and getting events sent it is just always missing those values from the dataLayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unchecking *Set default value* on the dataLayer variables. I believe that's overwriting any values you are passing. Also, what does your rule look like?

**EDIT:**
I found the problem. You need to have an event sent with the onclick.

**Steps to fix:**

Step 1: Create a new event macro. I typically call mine trackEvent.

[image]

Step 2: Add that event to your datalayer.push (the event macro is need in order to pass an event type action into GTM):

```
    dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'trackEvent',
      'location': 'header',
      'linkname': gaTrackInfo
    });
```

Step 3: Remove `{{url}} matches RegEx .*` and add `{{event}} equals trackEvent`:

[image]

Step 4: Publish container.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried unchecking that but it made no difference, everything again came through except my custom {{}} variables.  My rule is set to fire on all pages : `{{url}} matches RegEx .*`

Comment: WOO HOO!  That works.  Thanks so much I dont know if I would have ever figured this out from the existing docs.

Comment: yeah, took me a while to get figure that out too. There is some minor [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events) on it, but ya kinda gotta dig. Cheers